# In SQL filter out one column records based on different column condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 columns `Source_System`, `SBG_NAME`. I want to filter out `Source_System` Microsiga for `SBG_NAME` PMT

Data set is like this:

| Source_System | SBG_Name |
| --- | --- |
| CIP300 | PMT |
| Microsiga | PMT |
| CIP900 | HBT |
| Microsiga | HBT |

The output should be

| Source_System | SBG_Name |
| --- | --- |
| CIP300 | PMT |
| CIP900 | HBT |
| Microsiga | HBT |

Comment: are you looking for distinct rows ?

Comment: can you give more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
"Source_System"
,"SBG_Name"
FROM table

MINUS

SELECT
"Source_System"
,"SBG_Name"
FROM table
WHERE "Source_System" = 'Microsiga' and "SBG_Name" = 'PMT'
```

You could get the result with something like this. This shows all records, except the ones where Source_System is Microsiga and SBG_Name is PMT.

Alternatively this yields the same result and is even more compact:

```
SELECT
"Source_System"
,"SBG_Name"
FROM table
WHERE  NOT ("Source_System" = 'Microsiga' and "SBG_Name" = 'PMT')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or flipping SChnurres answer, and just not selection what you don't want

```
SELECT
    Source_System
    ,SBG_Name 
FROM VALUES 
  ('CIP300','PMT'),
  ('Microsiga','PMT'),
  ('CIP900','HBT'),
  ('Microsiga','HBT')
  v(Source_System,  SBG_Name)
WHERE NOT(Source_System = 'Microsiga' and SBG_Name = 'PMT');
```

gives:

| SOURCE_SYSTEM | SBG_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| CIP300 | PMT |
| CIP900 | HBT |
| Microsiga | HBT |